# Qt - On top of all notifications/windows

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am working on a mac fullscreen Qt app that basically have to reproduce some behaviors of a randsomware, meaning:

1. No shortcut avaible - DONE
2. No windows/notifications overlap mine - PROBLEM

I found a way to disable notifications from NotificationCenter while the app is running and reactivating it at the end but the problem is that even in fullscreen some windows can pop up from other apps and get over my app. To me, some working solutions to this problem could be :

1. Keep app on top such as 'windows' fullscreen video games does
2. Disable each application that could start right after my app started (so detect them)

It would be very great to have some other ideas to look for or a way to do what I previously say.

Thanks for your help and reply.

Sincerely

Comment: You say "reproduce ransomware behavior" but all I read is "I am creating ransomware"

Comment: Also, [What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: Sorry for my english, I'm learning it by myself, well it's only the basics of a ransomware, It doesn't have any malicious purpose. What I would really appreciate is a way to fullscreen like video games do. Without any notification or other windows disturbing the app.